# Laravel: How to use orderBy in Form?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and struggling with populating a form elements.

In database, I want to select a row with latest ID or latest created_by value but orderBy method does not seem to be working at all.

My code in view:

```
@php($deliveryNote = \App\DeliveryNote::where('order_id', $order->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first())
```

So it does not matter whether orderBy is present in a query, it still prints the first record with lowest ID. I also tried ->latest() as I found in other thread but this just prints an error.

Comment: try `last()` instead of `latest()`

Comment: you should n`t use eloquent queries in views

Comment: \App\DeliveryNote::where('order_id',$order_id)->latest('id')->first(); ?

Comment: Last and even latest() did not worked either. Tried every solution here now. Actually I did not write this website so I am just learning MVC patterns from it. So someone wrote equolent in blade and now I know it is not a good practice.

Comment: Actually I solved this one by deleting old rows.. so only 1 row is available in anytime request is made. Not an ideal solution but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

- never use eloquent queries in blade (views). its completely wrong, you should follow mvc structure.
- you should send this data from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Never use eloquent queries in blade file. its completely wrong.

You should follow mvc structure and try latest() function.

```
$deliveryNote = \App\DeliveryNote::where('order_id', $order->id)->latest()->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the **last** row of your table, try this

```
$last_row = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

This will let you to arrange your database table in DESCENDING order, then the **->first()** method fetches you first one (which is reversed, according to the order)

Comment: @LubWn try this one

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. I have it like:

`$deliveryNote = \App\DeliveryNote::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('order_id', $order->id)->first()`

Still retrieves wrong row. Not sure where I should look. I think problem is, that this is Order's blade view so maybe orderBy tries to order Orders instead of DeliveryNotes?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($institutes->sortBy('order') as $institute)

@endforeach
```

Comment: Little explanation to your code would be helpful, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

```
@php
//codes here
@endphp
```

This laravel's directive is only for plain PHP, so I don't think you can perform Eloquent relation in that.

Try this instead:

```
{{ $deliveryNote = \App\DeliveryNote::where('order_id', $order->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first() }}
```